# Meaning of TypeError

Tags: javascript, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am new to JavaScript and I don't get why the type of error that is thrown is called `TypeError` in the following code:

```js
"use strict"
var ob = {a: 1}; 
Object.defineProperty( ob, 'B', {value: 2, writable:false} ); 
ob.B; // => 2   
ob.B = 10;  
ob.B; // => 2
```

It should throw something like `UnassignableError`, because I cannot assign the value `10`.
Is there some value that I can assign to? What is the meaning of `TypeError` in JavaScript in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `UnassignableError` in javascript. The frequent list of errors can occur in javascript are

**EvalError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs regarding the global function eval().

**InternalError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when an internal error in the JavaScript engine is thrown. E.g. "too much recursion".

**RangeError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a numeric variable or parameter is outside of its valid range.

**ReferenceError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when de-referencing an invalid reference.

**SyntaxError**
    Creates an instance representing a syntax error that occurs while parsing code in eval().

**TypeError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.

**URIError**
    Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when encodeURI() or decodeURI() are passed invalid parameters.

So in the above errors TypeError will be thrown as error in the code with an explanation

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'B' of object '#<Object>'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **ECMAScript Specification** :

> When an assignment occurs within strict mode code, its LeftHandSide must not evaluate to an unresolvable reference. If it does a ReferenceError exception is thrown upon assignment. The LeftHandSide also may not be a reference to a data property with the attribute value {[[Writable]]:false}, to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:undefined}, nor to a non-existent property of an object whose [[Extensible]] internal property has the value false. In these cases a TypeError exception is thrown.

This error only occurs in strict mode. The assignment will fail without any error, without `use strict`, yielding totally unexpected results.